# Is there a defined value in the standard namespaces for the golden ratio?

Tags: c#

I was trying to find if there is a value for the golden ratio already defined in one of the standard namespaces but I was not able to find anything in the docs or other online resources.

So is there a value for the golden ratio already defined somewhere in the standard namespaces that I might have missed?

Under `Math` there is `Math.Pi` and `Math.E` but no `Math.Phi`?

Comment: I think you should select @Steve's answer

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No there is not. However, the [golden ratio](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenRatio.html) is the solution to *a number whose reciprocal is itself minus 1*:

[image: $\dfrac{1}{x} = x - 1\ \longrightarrow\ x^2 - x - 1 = 0$]

You can then solve that with the quadratic formula to get:

[image: $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} = 1.61803398874989484820458683436\mathellipsis$]

This means you can define the golden ratio as one of the following:

```
readonly double GoldenRatio = (1 + Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2;
const double GoldenRatio = 1.61803398874989484820458683436;
```

Answer (score 8):

No it isn't an already defined value for golden ratio. You have to build a method for the calculation of the golden ratio or you could declare a const variable, in which you will store this value.

```
const double goldenRatio = 1.61803398874989484820458683436;
```

Answer (score 7):

The Math.Net library contains a [definition](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Constants.htm#GoldenRatio) for the GoldenRatio, and its implementation matches the answer from @Steve above. It also includes a large number of other useful math-related functionality.